# Cannot archive project using Box iOS SDK 2.0

Tags: ios, box-api

My app builds and runs fine in the emulator and when installed from Xcode.  But, when I try to Archive the project for submission to Apple, I get a compile error saying BoxSDK/BoxSDK.h cannot be found.

How do I Archive with the iOS SDK 2.0?

Answer (score 1):

Add "$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)" in Header Search Path in Build setting

Answer (score 0):

Just configure following properties under build settings of your project

**GCC_PRECOMPILE_PREFIX_HEADER = YES;
GCC_PREFIX_HEADER = "FolderPicker-SampleApp/FolderPicker-SampleApp-Prefix.pch";
HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS = $(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)" and select non-recursive
INFOPLIST_FILE = "FolderPicker-SampleApp/FolderPicker-SampleApp-Info.plist";
IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = 5.0;**

After the above configuration try to archive

for more info please take a look here:[1]: https://github.com/box/box-ios-sdk-sample-app/commit/ab24c43c4741f690b65b6173e4c449b0ff268844